# Subversion WebDav troughs download windows on file view

Tags: download, webdav, svn

Upon upgrading to Ubuntu 10.10 on our dev machine we run into a small problem with the WebDav SVN. Now when we access a file it sends bin file type as header which triggers the browser to show the download window instead of displaying the file.

I didn't manage to find any similar problems and no configuration related to this.
Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i manage to fix it by adding

```
ForceType text/plain
```

in the httpd.conf location tag for svn